# Adding plugin settings link upon activation

Tags: plugin-development

Here I want to have upon activation of my wordpress plugins activation

Before Activation

```
Activate | Edit | Delete
```

After Activation

```
Settings | Edit | Delete
```

How can this be done in code to add this Menu

Comment: Those are called action links.

Answer (score 4):

Code extracted from my plugin, adapt as necessary.

```
add_filter( 'plugin_action_links', 'wpse_25030_settings_plugin_link', 10, 2 );

function wpse_25030_settings_plugin_link( $links, $file ) 
{
    if ( $file == plugin_basename(dirname(__FILE__) . '/many-tips-together.php') ) 
    {
        /*
         * Insert the link at the beginning
         */
        $in = '<a href="options-general.php?page=many-tips-together">' . __('Settings','mtt') . '</a>';
        array_unshift($links, $in);

        /*
         * Insert at the end
         */
        // $links[] = '<a href="options-general.php?page=many-tips-together">'.__('Settings','mtt').'</a>';
    }
    return $links;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public function my_plugin_action_links( $links ) {
       $mylinks[] = '<a href="'. get_admin_url(null, 'admin.php?page=settings') .'">'.__('Settings', 'woocommerce').'</a>';

       return $mylinks + $links;
    }
```

Adding `return $mylinks + $links;`, it orders the array

Comment: Your answer seems a little uncomplete. You should explain further what the code does and why it answers the question.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have so much time.